# Neo4j v2. Are aggregate functions usable as assignment (set) values?

Tags: count, neo4j, set, variable-assignment, aggregate

I can return an aggregate such as:

```
match (u:User)-[:LIKED]->(o:Offer) return count(u) as numLikes
```

...but I can't assign from it and keep it pre-counted for speed:

```
match (u:User)-[:LIKED]->(o:Offer) set o.numLikes = count(u)
```

Is this possible without using two separate statements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `WITH`:

```
MATCH (u:User)-[:LIKED]->(o:Offer) 
WITH o, count(u) AS c 
SET o.numLikes = c
```

Comment: Thanks - I was almost there(!) but wasn't including "o" before the count().

Answer (score 0):

You have to complete the aggregation before you can use the aggregated value, you can do this with `WITH`, something like

```
MATCH (u:User)-[:LIKED]->(o:Offer)
WITH o, COUNT(u) as numLikes
SET o.numLikes = numLikes
```